# how to define and use static variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define a static variable called index in my function, which does such as index++.
that means that if this method is called, the varaible will be added.

Comment: `const f = (() => { let index = 0; return () => index++; })();`

Answer (score 5):

We can use static variables in Typescript.

```
class Test {
    static index = 1;

    static print() {
        console.log(Test.index++);
    }
}
Test.print(); // prints 1
Test.print(); // prints 2
```